# How to Throw an error on duplicate Row Insertion in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, insert

I Have two fields `Aadhaar number` and `PAN Number` field `UNIQUE` into the database

My requirement is, whenever i Insert some duplicate entry, its just throw me an error

> Could Not Enter, Duplicate Aadhaar and/or PAN Number

Is there any way in MySQL to throw this kind of error?

Comment: Please provide the code of the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the error code. It is `1062` for duplicate key. You can handle this like below code.

```
mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO ...');
if (mysqli_errno($con) == 1062) {
    print 'Could Not Enter, Duplicate Aadhaar and/or PAN Number';
}
```

> use mysqli_errno() to retrieve the error code. Note that this function only returns the error code from the most recently executed MySQL function.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and they were removed in PHP 7.0.0 so you should never suggest using those

Comment: `mysqli_query` requires a link, that's the error that will show if the above snippet is used.